# How come my majestic palm has patchy dried out spots?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, watering, diseases

[image: dried spots on majestic palm]

[image]

This is an indoor pot plant. 
We have quite a bit of natural light thanks to a skylight, but not much direct sunlight unfortunately.

The dry patches have been there for a while and I’ve tried various things to get rid of them.
I have misted the plant daily. 
Have checked the leaves for spider mites or aphids and I’ve wiped all the leaves down in soapy water just in case. 
I put a tray beneath the pot with water and stones.
I have recently repotted the plant into a self watering pot, during which I noticed some tiny white bugs in the soil - which hopefully I’ve gotten rid of... not quite sure what they were but the internet says possibly soil mites which doesn’t seem dangerous to the plant anyways.

However the plant still does not seem happy. 
I’m at a loss for what else I can try? Any ideas?

Comment: has this plant had it's foliage touching a window during winter?

Comment: No it hasn’t - not that I know of!

Comment: What is your watering schedule?  What's the temperature of your house?